# Is there any documentation describing the naming convention of the stage names in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, naming-conventions

Is there any documentation describing the naming convention of the stage names in a Jenkinsfile?

```
node('base') {

    stage('unit test (java) xxxx xxxx') {
        ...}
    }
```

The stage like this (above) is quite long, and contains a bracket, just wondering if this is acceptable or if we can make it simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter any string as your stage name. So you have the freedom to make the name as simple as you want, as long it is a string.

[image]

[Source](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-stage-step/)